# How to set the taskbar progress indicator in a Powershell script?

Tags: windows, powershell

Powershell has a handy `Write-Progress` cmdlet which outputs to either the console itself in the form of an ASCII progress bar, or a traditional Windows progress bar if you run it hosted inside of the Powershell ISE.

Applications in windows can use their taskbar icon to indicate progress. How can I achieve this effect in Powershell?

Comment: `Get-Help Write-Progress -Online` it really tells you how to do all of what you're asking.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 `Write-Progress` doesn't set a progress indicator in the taskbar, please read my question again

Comment: Without editing the host titlebar name to correspond with `Write-Progress` or something of that nature, there's not an easy way to do so.

Comment: I don't think the name is mapped to the native indicator anyway, I'd imagine it would have to be with windows api calls